# Please use absolute timestamp in email notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timestamps, email-notification, tag-filters

I don't read my emails 24/7, and today read an email that was sent 2 days ago:

> [image]

The time stamps were correct in the time when the email was sent, but now they are pretty much useless.

Can you please put the actual date and time in those emails?

Worth to mention that previously (before the overhaul of the email notifications) there was no timestamp at all.

Also worth to mention that unlike the timestamps on the site itself, in the email they have no tooltip with the absolute time.

This also applies to unread inbox items notification:

> [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can sort of see this for inbox notifications, but even then... if you keep the emails, they sure do look weird.

This is fixed up now and we're using explicit date and time in both inbox notifications and tag filter emails. Let me know if you see any other emails that are using relative times.

Comment: Nice, and even a tooltip!